# how to fill out dhcp vendor specific option in dhcp packet

Tags: linux, dhcp

I want to create dhcp server on linux by use linux raw_socket.
But I can't find the way to fill out vender specific option in dhcp OFFER packet.
Please tell me how to do that or how to study that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some links to get you started:

http://www.ingmarverheij.com/microsoft-vendor-specific-dhcp-options-explained-and-demystified/

https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/udhcp/dhcpc.c

https://doc.freeradius.org/dhcp_8c_source.html